# get a google document by its title?

Tags: python, gdata

I want to read text from a google document using google drive API (and python).

With "gdata" module, I didn't find a way to get a document object by its title.
A module named gspread does just that.

(I don't know any other module besides gdata. "gspread" is a module that solves exactly this kind of questinos and simplifies the interaction with googleapi, but it's for spreadsheets, not for documents).

So far I know how to iterate over a list of all items in the "drive" (with GetDocumentListFeed) and get the relevant doc by comparing each item'ts title.text.

is there a way to do something like

```
item = client.get(title='lalala')
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but using the new Google Drive API. Using the [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) call and then a specific search query (See link below). If you are using the client library the call is as simple as:

```
file = client.files().list(q="title='YOUR TITLE'").execute()
```

This will return the items in your drive that match that title (in a dictionary). There are a lot more search queries that are possible if you visit [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters)